# Using bash for loop to iterate through file

Tags: bash, loops

I can iterate through a file, a.txt, performing an arbitrary command (echo in this example) on each line by doing

```
xargs -n1 echo < a.txt
```

or

```
for a in $(cat a.txt); do echo $a; done
```

Why can I not do something like

```
for arg do echo $arg; done < a.txt
```

which returns success but no output?

Comment: change `for arg` to `while read arg;` and it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, and indeed it does. I'm just wondering if a for loop similar to the one above would work. and if not, why.

Comment: `on each line by doing

xargs -n1` will not work with lines that contain odd number of  `'` or/and odd number of `"`. `or

for a in $(cat a.txt)` will not work with lines that has spaces or tabs between words.

Comment: `for arg; do ...` is equivalent to `for arg in "$@"; do ...`.  It does not take values from the input stream, but from the positional parameters.

Comment: [don't read lines of a file with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Expanding on why `for a in $(cat a.txt)` is a really bad idea: it doesn't read lines at all, it splits the file into "words" (using somewhat confusing rules), and then if any of those "words" look like filename wildcards, it tries to expand them into lists of matching filenames. This can have really bizarre consequences.

Comment: `for` loops split on any whitespace like space, tab, newline by default, the syntax `for` loops can be confusing. The best way to work on one line at a time is to use a `while read `loop instead, which splits on newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop takes its iteration values from its `in` clause or from the content of `$@`; it does not read from stdin.

In your last example, the entire command's stdin is being redirected from `a.txt` and it produces no output because `for` doesn't read from stdin and its command block's commands don't either.

The `read` command, however, does read from stdin and that's why the `while read arg;` loop works.

Credit to Glenn for explaining the meaning of a `for` command without an `in` clause:

The value of `$@` is empty and that is why your `for` loop produces no output. Redirecting a command's stdin from a file does not set `$@`. If you had placed that `for` loop in a script and executed it with some arguments, then your `for` loop would have printed the command line's arguments instead of the content of `a.txt`.

Comment: `for arg do ...` implicitly uses the positional parameters, and is equivalent to `for arg in "$@"; do`

Comment: @glennjackman I was wondering why it produced nothing on stderr. Now I know.